# error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist Androidx

Tags: androidx

What replaced package android.support.v7 in AndroidX

i cant find it in Androidx Releases

here's my app-level buidl.gradle dependencies:

d

```
ependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'


    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-alpha05'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha05'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'



    // Displaying images
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in dependencies
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

Comment: i got this :"Could not find appcompat.jar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0).
Searched in the following locations:

Answer (score 0):

You should add Maven of JetPack Library in Project Level build.gradle File.
Following is the code

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven
        {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```